# node.js: How to sync socket receive in 2 different routes

Tags: node.js

I am still learning `node.js` basics. My flow is like this,
`browser<-->node<-->backend server` doing calculation.

node and backend uses socket to communicate.

From the browser there are  start/stop buttons to ask backend to start/stop the 
calculation.

When node asks backend to start/stop, it must query to see if backend is 
alive first.

My code is like this -

```
app.get('/stopCmd', function(req, res)
{
    socketToBackendServer.write("status", function() {
        console.log("Sending:", 'Node asking for STATUS');
    });

    socketToBackendServer.on("data", function() {
        if(status is ok) // pseudo code
        {
            socketToBackendServer.write("stop", function() {
                console.log("Sending:", 'Node sending STOP');
            });
        } else {
            console.log("backend server is NOT ready");
        }
    });
});
app.get('/startCmd', function(req, res)
{
    // do similar things as stopCmd
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
var socketToBackendServer = net.connect(2899);
function openSocket() {
    socketToBackendServer.setKeepAlive(true);
    socketToBackendServer.on('connect', onConnect.bind({}, socketToBackendServer));
    socketToBackendServer.on('error', onError.bind({}, socketToBackendServer));
}


function onConnect(socket) {    
    var myData;

    console.log('Socket is open!');

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Received:', data);
        io.emit('time', { time: data.toJSON() });
    });
}

function onError(socket) {
    console.log('Socket error!');
    // Kill socket
    clearInterval(interval);
    socket.destroy();
    socket.unref();
    // Re-open socket
    setTimeout(openSocket, 1e3);
}

openSocket();

server.listen(7778);
```

if using the same browser, if i go crazy clicking start/stop... for the "
stopCmd", how to make sure when it queries "status", the response is caught 
by its function, not "startCmd"'s ? 
it's this line
socketToBackendServer.on("data", function()

Thank you again !

Comment: You missed to put the code.

Comment: finally figured out how to post code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple connections to the backend server, so one function can freely use one channel, the responses won't mix.

Or you can use a multiplexer function, that you call from both of your functions:

1. It could work if you can identify your requests, like you send and id with the status, for example socketToBackendServer.write("status 1", ... , and you send the id with the status response back from the backend server (if it yours). In this way you can send multiple requests at the same time, and when the response come, you can identify it, and call the callback function that you stored in an array with the ids.
2. You only send one request, and you wait for the response before you send another one. You must use a waiting queue, where you store the request, and the callback functions.

Comment: saw thinking about multiplexer as well, trying to see if there're better ways, :)